# How to remove dynamic created TextField in another function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Im currently creating textfields in a for loop - though in this example only creating one TextField.

My questions is, how do I remove the TextField child in another function?
What im basically doing is, create a Textfield, addchild to a container - > then the container into another position - > then removechild and another text in the container. I've tried something like:

removeChild( getChildByName(myTextField2) );

*edit:* perhaps a solution for me could also just to be able to change the text of the TextField to something else, rather than removing it and adding a new one.

```
public function handleTextFrames(numberOfFrames:Number, textFrame1:String, textFrame2:String, textFrame3:String, textFrame4:String):void

    {

        var textArray:Array = new Array(textFrame1,textFrame2,textFrame3,textFrame4);

        // Creating font instance
        var garageInstance:Font = new garage();

        //Creating the textfield object and naming it "myTextField"
        var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();

        //Here we add the new textfield instance to the stage with addchild()
        textContainer.alignContainer1.addChild(myTextField);

        //myTextField.width = 930;
        myTextField.embedFonts = true;
        myTextField.multiline = true;
        myTextField.wordWrap = false;
        myTextField.selectable = false;

        var myText:String = textArray[0];

        myTextField.htmlText = myText;

        //This last property for our textfield is to make it autosize with the text, aligning to the left.
        myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

        //This is the section for our text styling, first we create a TextFormat instance naming it myFormat
        var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

        //Embedding font
        myFormat.font = garageInstance.fontName;

        myFormat.color = 0xffffff;
        myFormat.size = 60;
        myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;


        //Now the most important thing for the textformat, we need to add it to the myTextField with setTextFormat.
        myTextField.setTextFormat(myFormat);

        myTextField.y = textContainer.alignContainer1.height * 0.5 - myTextField.textHeight * 0.5;
        myTextField.x = payoffContainer_mc.width / 2 - myTextField.textWidth / 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do? :) Because if you keep the textfields in a "global" array, that would solve it.

Let's say you keep it in an array, called `textfields`.

```
var textfields:Array = [];
```

You push everything in to this, by

```
textfields.push(textfield);
```

Then, at any time, you can remove this by calling this function:

```
textfields[0].parent.removeChild(textfields[0]);
```

concerning the first element. In flash this always works:

```
INSTANCE.parent.removeChild(INSTANCE);
```

Does this help?

Comment: That last code example "always works" IF the instance has a parent, otherwise it'll cause a runtime error (due to the null parent).

Comment: The question was how to "remove" a TextField. From this question, it was obvious, that the instance is added to the stage, therefore it has a parent.

Comment: anemgyenge! The global array did the trick for me - i'm so sorry for the slow reponse, but I didnt get any notification from here, not sure why! - Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First give the textfield a name:

```
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.name = "mytextfield";
```

Then you access it by doing this:

```
var myTextField:TextField = textContainer.alignContainer1.getChildByName("mytextfield");
```

Remove it:

```
textContainer.alignContainer1.removeChild(myTextField);
myTextField = null;
```

Comment: You could just access the textfield and change it values without removing and adding it over and over again.

Comment: accessing the textfield and changing it's value, was a actually an easier approach for me - so thanks for the suggestion Ancide!

Answer (score 0):

For one, instead of getChildByName - consider just using this method:

```
container["text_field_name"];
```

Also I recommend making your removeChild() call a little stricter to avoid null object reference errors:

```
var tf:TextField = TextField(container["text_field_name"]);

if(tf.parent) tf.parent.removeChild(tf);
```

All you need to have access to from your function that you want to remove this from is "container" which is the **parent** of the TextField, and the TextField itself.

Hope this helps.